# Error while compiling Ogre code

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ogre

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Ogre: v1.9

I am trying to compile code from this [repository](https://github.com/ogre3d/clean-project). Although it is meant for Ogre v1.9, it is giving me this error:

```
In file included from /home/cortana/Desktop/clean-project/src/BaseApplication.cpp:17:0:
/home/cortana/Desktop/clean-project/src/BaseApplication.h:34:22: fatal error: SdkTrays.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/OgreApp.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/OgreApp.dir/src/BaseApplication.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/OgreApp.dir/src/BaseApplication.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/OgreApp.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/OgreApp.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: _"How can I fix this error?"_ Make sure that `SdkTrays.h` exists.

Comment: The `SdkTrays.h` is meant as a part of library code in ogre <1.9. On 1.9 we are not provided that file.Copying it from somewhere else and putting it there leads to loads of other errors.

Comment: It's sad how Ogre team can't make the tutorials agree with the zip files they distribute.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, you need to make sure that your compiler is able to find the file "*SdkTrays.h*".

You claimed that this file is not part of Ogre version 1.9, which however is not correct. It could be that it is not part of the unofficial repository you are using. In our official one, it can be found here:

[SdkTrays.h in official Ogre 1.9](http://bitbucket.org/sinbad/ogre/src/108ab0bcc69603dba32c0ffd4bbbc39051f421c9/Samples/Common/include/SdkTrays.h)

Comment: I installed ogre using apt-get on Ubuntu. I used this command specifically:`sudo apt-get install libogre-1.9-dev` for installation. My cmake file detects the ogre installation but still gives this error. How do I make it find the SDKtrays.h file?